# llamar una funcion desde el frontend angular a backend nodejs usando express

Tags: nodejs, express

Como verán estoy creando un proyecto que utiliza angular, express, nodejs y mysql pero me encontré con un problema, como llamar una función teniendo múltiples funciones."cabe aclarar que aun soy una persona novicia"

Backend:

Tengo mi archivo:

```
**routes.js** 
const controls=require('../controllers/controls/controls');

router.post('/idpost',controls.postfunction);
```

Aqui es donde tengo mi ruta para hacer las peticiones post.

Por otro lado tengo mi archivo

```
**controls.js **
exports.getid=(req, res)=>{

};
exports.getname=(req, res)=>{
};

exports.postfunction = (req, res )=>{
querypost.entrade(req,res);
querypost.additems(req,res);
};
```

Aqui lo agrege para hacerlo mas modular ocupando la documentacion.

Este es mi grupo de funciones lo separe del archivo controls.js para poder reutilizarlo en otras futuras llamadas

```
postquery.js

function entrade(){ ..};
function additems(){...};
function users(){...};

module.exports={ entrade,addditems };
```

El detalle es como llamar a una sola funcion desde el frontend usando angular o enviar parametros a una o funciones en especifico

Escuche algo de fetch y xmlhttprequest  o utilizar httpclientmodule pero como veran aun sigo aprendiendo  asi que si me pueden ayudar con mucho gusto se los agradecere.

Comment: No vas a enviar funciones, vas a hacer requests Http. En Angular usas el HttpClientModule, como es código que probablemente (y deberías) reutilizar lo tienes que poner en un servicio. Ya ahí haces el método para hacer GET, POST, PUT y DELETE y mandas llamar el servicio en el componente que necesites. Descarga Postman para probar tus requests. Otra cosa, si apenas estas aprendiendo Angular empieza primero por aprender lo básico de Typescript.

Comment: Claro verificare bien las requests y utilizare el modulo HttpClient.
Y si ando tambien ando aprendiendo lo basico de Ts.